# How to use EWS API with Console App Net Core

Tags: .net-core, console-application, ews-managed-api

I'm trying to use this Net Standard package https://github.com/sherlock1982/ews-managed-api to connect to Exchange in a Console App with .Net Core.

The Autodiscovery apparently doesn't find the server and I can't get an Exchange Response after Send() email.

Same code works flawlessly in ASP.Net Core Web Api.

I guess it's some package reference stuff but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you provide some code? Exceptions? Stack trace? Expected behaviour? I think we'll need a little more to go on..

Comment: It's exactly this code from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-managed-api-client-applications

Comment: But in a Net Core Console

Comment: You will have to build the EWS-Managed-api form source with targeting the dot net core. Someone may already have that as nuget package, look for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out.

The **.Net Standard version of EWS API is totally async**, which means I must handle it properly.

As I'm not concerned about parallelism, I've used **Wait** method to sync wait for it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netcore-2.1

Comment: Hi, i tried to use the Wait method but there is no response after I used the Send(). No email is received. and I couldn't see the mail in the sent box too. How do you use the EWS API in console app?

Comment: Are you on Exchange or 365?

Comment: I'm on Exchange 2016

Answer (score 0):

For those finding this question while searching how to connect to an onpremise Exchange installation from .net core:

I found that the Nuget Package mentioned by op had various bugs. Thats why I searched an alternative. In the end I found that the safest and easiest was to download the entire repository [ews-managed-api](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api) and ported it myself to .net standard using the visual studio "upgrade assistant"-extension.

I had it working within less than an hour. No unknown reference to unthrusted dll, no unexpected bugs, ...

To connect to Exchange within Office365, Microsoft recommends using [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/dotnet?tabs=aad) which I beleave is available for .net core.

Answer (score -1):

You should use EWS Subscription mechanism if you want to handle more than ~20 mailboxes to be monitored.

Comment: So what is the recommended approach for sending e-mails using a single mailbox?

Comment: Use  EWS subscription. This avoids regular polling thing.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't get it. You said that EWS subscriptions should be used if I was handling more the 20 mailboxes.

Comment: EWS Subscription can be used even for single mailbox too. In fact, I would suggest you go with subscription path for your single mailbox.  It avoids polling thing which result in save of bandwidth and CPU usage compare to regular polling. Also, it makes your code robust and scalable for future changes.